How to determine variables in Directus Flows
I'm stuck at determine variables on directus flows.
I know there is {{$trigger.payload.field}} and it works. But I need read data from other collection so called it tablex. So I use operation "Read Data" and set a key like "read_tablex". It works.
read_tablex give  one result like this:
[
{
"id": 12,
"address": "somewhere in the world",
}
]
I need address's value. Already tried: {{$last[0].address}} or {{$read_tablex[0].address}} or {{$read_tablex.address}} or {{$read_tablex.payload.address}} or {{$read_tablex.payload[0].address}} still no luck. Please help.

You should be able to access the data using {{read_tablex.address}}, without using $ sign at the beginning.
You can check out this video starting at 51:45 as a reference.
